# Method For A RESTful "Copy"

Tags: rest

I am working on a node.js based REST API for managing files on a remote system. To create a new file with contents I'm currently issuing a PUT request to a URI where the body of the request contains the file contents. To retrieve the contents of a file, a GET request is issued and the response body contains the file contents.

I'm having difficulty determining a good way to implement a copy capability however. The only effective method I have currently is to issue a GET, retrieve the source file, then resend the contents with a PUT request.

One idea I've explored is issuing a PUT request for the destination file with data in the header identifying the source file to copy data from. However, with the APIs design that wouldn't be exactly ideal, but would work if necessary.

Ideally I would like to be able to issue a PUT request for the destination file and basically redirecting the body of a GET request for the source file into the body of the PUT request without downloading the entire file contents to the client first.

**My question is**, is there an effective/appropriate way that I can issue an HTTP/S PUT request specifying that the body contents should be the body of a GET request to a different URI without first downloading it to the client?

Example of API current bahaviors:

Get file contents (sourcefile.ext)

```
GET https://server.com/directory/sourcefile.ext
# the body of the response if good is the file contents
```

Create file with contents (destinationfile.ext)

```
PUT https://server.com/directory/destinationfile.ext
# the body of the request is the desired file contents
```

Ideal copy functionality (sourcefile.ext -> destinationfile.ext)

```
PUT https://server.com/directory/destinationfile.ext
# somehow tell the request to pull the body from a GET request to 
# https://server.com/directory/sourcefile.ext
# being made by the API server rather than the client issuing both requests
# in succession
```

Yes a `PUT https://server.com/directory/destinationfile.ext?copySourceFile=sourcefile.ext` could be used, and I will use that if I must, but there are no `?var1=val1&var2=val2` queries used anywhere else in the API currently (they are not needed anywhere else) and I'd like to keep the requests standardized if I can help it.

Comment: post your code so that the problem can be reproduced and worked on

Comment: It's not a question about specific code. More so a way to prompt a certain behavior in the HTTP/S protocols agnostic of a certain language or codebase. (Plus the minimal working client and server side code relevant to this would be far longer than is appropriate for a question about a transfer protocol.)

Comment: It's your API, is there some reason you can't offer a GET request where the parameters are existing-file, copy-location?  The responses would be OK or ACCESS DENIED or FILE DOES NOT EXIST or INVALID COPY NAME.

Comment: I can and currently a test implementation of something similar is in the API, but it goes against the general behaviors throughout the rest of the API. Thus far, every function has the exact same request format just using a different request method for the HTTP/S request and that prompts the different bahaviors. I CAN do that but if there is any way to make HTTP/S follow the desired behavior in the question, that would be the preferable route.

Comment: I've updated the question with an example case

Answer (score 1):

Why limit yourself to GET and PUT?  Clearly you can do a POST request to do whatever you want.  You could POST to the source the URL to copy itself to.  You could POST to the target with the URL to to copy from.  Or you could POST both URLs to a copy object (I know, not the best form, but not illegal either).

GET and PUT only work when you have a single resource involved.  You have two resources.  Any operation involving more than one resource must use POST and you have quite a bit of latitude in how you use it.

Comment: The only functions needed are "Retrieve File", "Create File", "Delete File", "Retrieve File Info", and "Copy File To New Location". Which are currently done with identical request formats using GET, PUT, DELETE, and HEAD respectively (Copy excluded of course) where the body of each request or response body is just the file contents. POST would work, but break the pattern as the body would be information on what to copy rather than file contents. It's not that it's not possible to make it do what I want, it's making it do what I want and maintain a consistent API behavior.

Comment: I'm with @AgilePro - your PUT to create a new file should be a POST to adhere to the REST (and HTTP verb) principle of PUT being [idempotent](https://stormpath.com/blog/put-or-post#idempotency) and POST being non-idempotent. That makes the answer for the copy be POST as well. Both are creating new resources at a given URI, which is what POST is for.

Comment: "Consistency for consistency sake" is a misguided goal.  When you are doing things that are similar, it makes sense to make the command as similar as possible.  But when you are something fundamentally different, it is right and appropriate to make the command different.  Forcing two things that are NOT identical, to APPEAR identical tends in real life to make it more confusing.  While the goal to avoid arbitrary differences is laudable, when the difference is justified as it is in this case, your API will benefit by making the commands different.  "Appropriateness" > "blind consistency"